# How can I detect heap corruption in my case

Tags: c++, visual-c++, heap-memory

I want to convert my STRUCT with respect for the following approach:

- convert STRUCT to array of char.
- convert table of char to array of int.
- convert array of int to array of char.
- convert array of char to STRUCT.

But I have those erreur when running: 
[image]
[image]

This is my code:

```
void rServer::convertStruct_to_char ( PCryptDATA p) {

    // ***********convert struct to Array of char ************
    char* frame= new char[p.size];
    cout << p.size <<endl;
    cout << endl;   
    memcpy(frame, &p, sizeof(p));


    //***********convert Array of char to array of int  ************
    int taille= p.size;
    int* out = new int[taille]; 
    for (int i=0; i<taille+1;i++) 
    {
        out[i]=frame[i];
    }

    delete [] frame;

    //***********convert Array of int to Array of char ************
    char* int2char = new char[taille];
    for (int i=0; i<taille+1;i++)
    {
        int2char[i]=out[i];
    }

    //delete [] int2char;

    //***********convert Array of char to STRUCT ************
    PCryptDATA t; //Re-make the struct
    memcpy(&t, int2char, sizeof(t));
}
```

Can you help me please to find the cause of this problem when running.

Comment: You're writing one character past the end of `out` and `int2char`: either the size should be `taille+1`, or the loop bound should be `taille`. Also, there's some confusion between `p.size` and `sizeof(p)`.

Comment: C style functions in C++ are severely frowned upon. You have the STL and iterators, why are you writing loops by hand and playing with pointers?

Comment: Also, `char` is typically 1 byte while `int` is two bytes. By copying ints into a char array you will mangle the data.

Comment: @ Mike Seymour, I din't understand what is the confusion you noticed between p.size and sizeof(p) !!

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanvos, I must respect a struct that have char* as member that's why I have to write loop by hand. Can you telle me please how Can I handle conversion of int array to char array ?

Comment: @SADOK: You allocate `p.size` bytes, then (try to) copy `sizeof(p)` bytes into it. If those two sizes aren't the same, then you might overrun the end of the array.

Comment: p.size is big enough.

Comment: I really don't find a convincing answer to this error !

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int* out = new int[taille]; 
for (int i=0; i<taille+1;i++) 
    out[i]=...
```

is bad - in the last iteration of the loop you assign a value to `out[taille]`, but `out` array was allocated for `taille` elements indexed from `0` trough `taille-1`. As a result you write past the allocated block and overwrite some other block of the heap, thus corrupting it.

Should be:

```
int* out = new int[taille]; 
for (int i=0; i<taille;i++) 
    out[i]=...
```

Same for other `for` loops.

Comment: A worse error is copying 1-byte `char` arrays to 2-byte `int` arrays and back. The data will definitely be mangled and with the `int2char` you'' also overrun the end of the buffer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos AFAIK a value copied from `char` to `int` may get sign bit extended - but that does not affect 8 least significant bits. When copied back to `char` those `int` values are simply truncated, so the source value gets restored. What mangling do you mean?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, But when I use debugger I find that my struct is very well copied and I have the same data that I used from the beginning.